# Dango Queryset filter and pagination

Tags: python, django, django-models, pagination, django-queryset

Is there any way to make django paginator to work with filtering and sorting without the involvement of
django-filter. This is my code now:

```py
def check_filters(post, content):
    if some_filter := post.gelist("some_filter"):
       content = content.filter(some_filter=some_filert)
    if ....basically the same ....
    if ...basically the same ....
    return content

def some_fun(response):
    n = SomeQueryset.objects.all();
    if post:= response.POST:
        n = check_filters(post, n, )
    paginator = Paginator(n, per_page=12)
    page_number = response.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        
    return render(response, 'store/store.html', {"page_obj": page_obj, "colors": get_colors()})
```

Comment: Wht is not working with the current approach?

Comment: the pagination resets the filters and vice versa

Comment: @EvegeniGenchev: but typically filtering is done through the querystring, not through a POST request, otherwise you will need to make *another* POST request for the next pages.

Comment: I have followed the default django example and made this via ajax. The page doesn't refresh and the filters do not reset. You just have to play with it with some JavaScript.